# Array of closures within a class

Tags: php

It appears you can't have an array of callable methods defined within the scope of a class. Why not?

Why is this valid PHP (see http://3v4l.org/1JeQr)

```
$methods = array(
    1 => function($subject, $value){
        return ($subject == $value);
    }
);

var_dump($methods[1]('a', 'a'));
```

But not this (see http://3v4l.org/FL449)

```
class Foo {
    public static $methods = array(
        1 => function($subject, $value){
            return ($subject == $value);
        }
    );
}

var_dump(Foo::$methods[1]('a', 'a'));
```

Comment: [This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: I would have thought a closure would adhere to this rule. They're constant and don't depend on any run-time information for evaluation. Or do they? http://3v4l.org/cY4Zt

Comment: The question: "Why not?"

Comment: Peter: Your example clearly performs an evaluation of (2 + 2) for assignment. The closure (in my example) doesn't depend on any run time information or perform any kind of evaluation in its declaration.

Comment: Yeah sorry. PHP actually creates some [mangled object thingy](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_closures.c#32)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very quick answer since I am working from mobile phone (can eventually edit later.

Defining a closure actually performs an instantiation of an object of type `Closure`. PHP only supports native internal types as default values for your classes, which means that constructing a closure obviously won't work.

Comment: That makes complete sense, thanks Marco. It's an object under the hood and so it's equivocal to doing "new Bar()". An unfortunate limitation. It's a shame, as it would be quite nice if they were handled differently and this functionality was possible.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the property definitions in a class only allow you to assign ***simple, direct values***. Class constant assigning is further more restrictive.
This means that no values derived from a function, no arrays that are filled with derived values or objects, or any arithmetic are allowed in the property definition scope.

If you want to assign an array of closures upon the initialization of the object, you can freely do so in the construct of the class. Like this:

```
class Foo {
    public static $methods;

    function __construct() {
        $this->methods = array(
                               1 => function($subject, $value) {
                                       return ($subject == $value);
                                    }
                               );
    }
}
```